# Passing --project to ts-node when it's registered with nodemon

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, nodemon, ts-node

This command is used to run my server:<sup>1</sup>

```sh
nodemon
  -r ts-node/register
  -r tsconfig-paths/register
  --watch server/
  --watch shared/
  --ext ts,tsx,json
  --inspect-brk=24170
  ./server/index.ts
```

The problem is, I need `ts-node` to receive `--project ./tsconfig-server.json` rather than using the default `tsconfig.json`. Simply including it after the `-r ts-node/register` (or anywhere else) results in a `bad option: --project` error.

Using `--exec 'node ./node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js --project ./tsconfig-amd.json'` instead of `-r ts-node/register` works, but then the debugger fails to attach to the process. I assume that’s because it’s trying to attach to the nodemon process rather than the node process that nodemon starts?

But I cannot use the default `tsconfig.json` filename here, because [VS Code does not support specifying an alternative `tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12463) and the server config is not the one I want to use for viewing and editing the code

---

1. <sub>The command is actually produced by VS Code per my `.vscode/launch.json` which looks like this:</sub>

   ```json
   {
       // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
       // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
       // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
           {
               "type": "node",
               "request": "launch",
               "name": "nodemon",
               "runtimeExecutable": "node",
               "args": [
                   "${workspaceFolder}/server/index.ts"
               ],
               "runtimeArgs": [
                   "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js",
                   "-r",
                   "ts-node/register",
                   "-r",
                   "tsconfig-paths/register",
                   "--watch",
                   "server/",
                   "--watch",
                   "shared/",
                   "--ext",
                   "ts,tsx,json"
               ],
               "restart": true,
               "console": "integratedTerminal",
               "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
               "protocol": "inspector"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

Comment: did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: @EhouarnPerret No, I didn’t; I ended up giving up, and using `tsconfig.json` for the server config instead of the client config as I’d wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the `--project` value trough the "TS_NODE_PROJECT" environment variable.
I do it in my `nodemon.json` file

```
{
    "restartable": "rs",
    "ignore": [".git", "node_modules/**/node_modules", "src/client"],
    "verbose": true,
    "execMap": {
      "ts": "node --require ts-node/register/transpile-only --require tsconfig-paths/register"
    },
    "watch": ["src/server", "typing"],
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "development",
      "TS_NODE_PROJECT": "src/server/tsconfig.json"
    },
    "ext": "js,json,ts"
}
```

Comment: It's also possible to add it directly to `package.json`: `"nodemonConfig": {
    "env": {
      "TS_NODE_PROJECT": "server/tsconfig.json"
    }
  }`. More info given at nodemon docs (https://github.com/remy/nodemon#nodemon).